# Extracting JSON embeded in a webpage code

Tags: python, json

I've been experimenting with some web scraping solutions lately.

I'm trying to extract specific elements of JSON code embedded in a web page (https://www.instagram.com/p/BxII02-A9wb/).

I'm interested in isolating the comments section details with a special interest in the text and author details:

```
"comment":[  
    {  
     "@type":"Comment",
     "text":"Pior operadora de sempre, nunca vi uma internet t\\u00e3o lenta como a vossa, fico feliz em dizer que quando o contrato acabar vou mudar para a Vodafone, \\u00e9 mais barato e tem uma qualidade de net no m\\u00ednimo 10 vezes melhor. Recomendo a todos a vodafone ou at\\u00e9 mesmo a MEO que pode n\\u00e3o ser perfeita mas sempre \\u00e9 melhor que a NOS( o que n\\u00e3o \\u00e9 dif\\u00edcil)",
     "author":{  
        "@type":"Person",
        "alternateName":"@filipe389",
        "mainEntityofPage":{  
           "@type":"ProfilePage",
           "@id":"https:\\/\\/www.instagram.com\\/filipe389\\/"
        }
     }
  }
```

]

I'm using BeautifulSoup and Selenium to perform the scraping task and json.loads to handle the json section (after having it isolated). But when I try to access the contents of the comments section I'm not being aable to access the data I want to:

```
for data in jsonData:
    if data == "comment":
    results.append(data) #also tried results.append(data[6]) and results.append(data['comment')
```

I think that my problem is that I'm dealing with a string instead of a dictionary but, so far, I haven't been able to come up with a working solution.

I'm also trying to apply regular expressions but so far haven't been able to achieve any viable solution.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BxII02-A9wb/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
insta_data = soup.find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")

for contents in insta_data:
    contents.text

jsonData = json.loads(contents.text) 

results = []
for data in jsonData:
    if data == "comment":
        results.append(data)

print(results)
browser.close()
```

Basically I want to access info such as the comment itsef,

"Pior operadora de sempre, nunca vi uma internet t\u00e3o lenta como a vossa, fico feliz em dizer que quando o contrato acabar vou mudar para a Vodafone, \u00e9 mais barato e tem uma qualidade de net no m\u00ednimo 10 vezes melhor. Recomendo a todos a vodafone ou at\u00e9 mesmo a MEO que pode n\u00e3o ser perfeita mas sempre \u00e9 melhor que a NOS( o que n\u00e3o \u00e9 dif\u00edcil)",

as well as the author handlename "@filipe389".

In the example I posted here, I'm getting just "comment" in returning and "t" when I use
    results.append(data[6])

Any tip or suggestion will be most welcome!

Thanks!

Miguel

Comment: This is just a dictionary. You access dictionary data via its keys. I don't know what you are trying to do with that for loop, or with `data[6]` - why 6?

Comment: Hi, also tried that.

   `for data in jsonData:`
     `if data == "comment":`
      `results.append(data['comment'])`

Got the following output:     `results.append(data['comment'])`
_**TypeError: string indices must be integers**_

Comment: Iterating over a dictionary gives you just the keys. But why are you iterating at all? As I say, if `jsonData` is a dictionary, `jsonData['comment']` gives you the comment value. No need to iterate or compare; that's just not how you use dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, no need to iterate. But if you are itereating over a dictionary and want both the key and values, you would need to use `.items()`:

I wouldn't iterate, but just to show you with your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/BxII02-A9wb/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
insta_data = soup.find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")

results = []
for contents in insta_data:
    jsonData = json.loads(contents.text) 

    for key, value in jsonData.items():
        if key == "comment":
            results.append(value)

author = results[0][0]['author']['alternateName']
text = results[0][0]['text']

print ('%s:\n%s' %(author, text))

browser.close()
```

Since the json/dictionary has what you need, just call out what you need directly by using the keys and indexes of the data structure:

```
insta_data = soup.find_all("script", type="application/ld+json")[0]
jsonData = json.loads(insta_data.text) 

author = jsonData['comment'][0]['author']['alternateName']
text = jsonData['comment'][0]['text']

print ('%s:\n%s' %(author, text))
```

**Output:**

```
print ('%s:\n%s' %(author, text))
@filipe389:
Pior operadora de sempre, nunca vi uma internet tão lenta como a vossa, fico feliz em dizer que quando o contrato acabar vou mudar para a Vodafone, é mais barato e tem uma qualidade de net no mínimo 10 vezes melhor. Recomendo a todos a vodafone ou até mesmo a MEO que pode não ser perfeita mas sempre é melhor que a NOS( o que não é difícil)
```